# Spring Security JWT Filter

Tags: spring-security, jwt

Есть микросервисная архитектура.
Сервис подключен к серверу авторизации с использованием JWT токенов.

Настройка авторизации на сервисе:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigSecured extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt();
    }
}
```

После прохождения авторизации из контекста спринга можно вытащить

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
```

Но мне нужно из Jwt токена вытащить кастомные поля, например

```
String user_custom_field;
```

Для этого, я создал:

```
public class JwtUser extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    private String user_custom_field;
// далее необходимые конструкторы, геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

И вот дальше, я хочу, чтоб в контексте спринга был именно JwtUser...

Я пытался запихнуть его в контекст при помощи

> .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(),
>   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt();
    }
```

Для чего создал:

```
public class JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String parsedToken = request.getHeader(TOKEN_HEADER).replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
    try {    
        Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(parsedToken.substring(0, parsedToken.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
        if (claims.getSubject() != null) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<String> authorities = claims.get("groups", List.class);

            // 1. Create auth object
            JwtUser jwtUser = new JwtUser(
                    claims.getSubject()
                    , null
                    , authorities.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList())
                    , claims.get("user_custom_field", String.class)
            );
            // 2. Authenticate the user
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(jwtUser);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // In case of failure. Make sure it's clear; so guarantee user won't be authenticated
        log.error("", e);
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }
    // go to the next filter in the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Ну и дальше в коде, я пытаюсь получить авторизованного JwtUser из контекста спринга:
`log.info("Authentication class is {}",SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());`

получаю:

```
Authentication class is org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken@ef95dfc: Principal: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@f9381dc5; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@3bcc: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.21.168; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_offline_access, SCOPE_microprofile-jwt, SCOPE_address, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_profile, SCOPE_phone
```

Что я делаю не так???